# ZoneOffset calculation with cache

Tags: java, time, java-time

Why is `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(int totalSeconds)` using a cache for the **ZoneOffset** only when totalSeconds are multiples of a quarter of an hour?

```
if (totalSeconds % (15 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE) == 0) {
            Integer totalSecs = totalSeconds;
            ZoneOffset result = SECONDS_CACHE.get(totalSecs);
            if (result == null) {
            (...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most zone offsets in use today are a multiple of a quarter of an hour, for example

```
Europe/Ljubljana     +02:00
America/Boa_Vista    -04:00
Asia/Brunei          +08:00
Pacific/Wake         +12:00
Asia/Colombo         +05:30
Asia/Kathmandu       +05:45
```

Since such are used often, it is worth caching them. If used in your program, it’s not so unlikely that they will be used again in your program or another program running in the same JVM. Other offsets have been used historically or never at all, so are not worth caching. Even if you use one once, they considered that probability that you use the same again low enough that they didn’t want to cache it until the JVM closes down (which could be in weeks or even months from now).

I’m not claiming to be a mind reader, but the explanation that I have given makes sense to myself and I would suppose that if not 100 % correct, it catches the most important thoughts that have been behind the decision taken. Things are slightly more complicated. For example not that many offsets not divisible by a whole hour are in use, but they opted for a simple condition.